# Kibana distinct values on query

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Do you know if it's possible to retrieve results on kibana using a 'distinct' approach?

I have several entries that contains the same message, except for time stamp. I want to distinct only for the message part. My entry is something similar to this:

```
04.05.2017 13:00:13.005 *ERROR* [pool-6-thread-4] <my log error goes here>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Other than a Vizualisation of type Data Table, I don't see any other hack to make it work